# Creating Tables with the same table names from other databases doesn't have any bad effects?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wordpress, web-server

I have a WordPress website and I cloned it to another website(domain) using a plugin called Duplicator. So in the backend, phpMyAdmin, I've two different databases but all the tables in both databases have the same names.

[image]

**I just want to make sure that this does not have any kind of bad effects.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem.

```
USE mumer_watches;
SELECT ... FROM wp58_posts
```

will refer, unambiguously, to the table `mumer_watches.wp58_posts`.  Ditto for

```
SELECT ... FROM mumer_watches.wp58_posts
```

Assuming this is WordPress, well, that's the way it works.

Comment: I don't have to do any operations on databases manually, the CMS (WordPress) automatically does it. I think there won't be any problem because they are two different databases and two different websites. What do you think?

Comment: @UmerMansoor - Nothing to worry about.  (I added some text.)

Answer (score 0):

word press has a variable for the database, as long as you have the configuration correct it will apply to all script automatically.

So you have no worries about which database you are using

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'database_name_here' );
```

explanation for the [config file](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/)

If you want to know mre abour identifiers

[mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html)

and [maria db](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/identifier-names/)